# Borel and Lebesgue measurability of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and suppose $f'$ exists on $(0,1)$.

Is it true to say that $f'$ is Borel measurable? Or Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous we know $f$ is Borel measurable. We know $$f'(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$$ so $f'$ is Borel measurable (and hence Lebesgue measurable too).

Comment: Ah, you were faster, +1.